# TypeError: Cannot read property of instance

Tags: actionscript-3, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I'm trying to make eye following for cursor like this http://www.flashuser.net/eyes-following-mouse-cursor-as3 in Adobe Animate 2015

```
function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left,
    y: mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    mousePos = getMousePos(this, e);

    var xx = mousePos.x - this.Reye.x;
    var yy = mousePos.y - this.Reye.y;
    var radiusR1 = Math.atan2(yy, xx);
    var degreeR1 = radiusR1 / (Math.PI / 180);
    this.Reye.rotation = degreeR1;

}, false);
```

but i have error in browser

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

and this code is working fine

```
this.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));
function fl_MouseClickHandler(evt)
{
    var xx = stage.mouseX - this.Reye.x;
    var yy = stage.mouseY - this.Reye.y;
    var radiusR1 = Math.atan2(yy, xx);
    var degreeR1 = radiusR1 / (Math.PI / 180);
    this.Reye.rotation = degreeR1;
}
```

Comment: function (e) looks fishy

Comment: function works but i can't get access to element "Reye"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is wrong.

You add an anonymous function as a listener inline:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
```

This is bad practise btw., because you have a hard time removing the listener again. A lingering listener will prevent objects from getting collected and can cause memory leaks.

Anyway, the scope of an anonymous function (closure) is the global object. `this` will not point to the scope where the function is defined.

In your second example, you bind the scope:

```
fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this)
```

which shouldn't be necessary for a named function.

On a side note: use types and use defined constants for Event types, such as `MouseEvent.CLICK` for `"click"` - prevents typos and allows code completion.

Comment: thx, i use `stage.on("stagemousemove", fl_MouseMove.bind(this));` and its work with a named function